# Ошибка Run-time check failure #2

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, runtime

Ошибка run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted. При дебаге он все хорошо делает, а в самом конце, когда результаты выданы и все хорошо он выдает эту ошибку. Не очень понимаю как это пофиксить. Может кто подсказать?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

void minmax(int arrays[], int n);
void bubble(int arr[], int n);

void main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
const int n = 21;
int a[n];
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
cout << "Исходный массив = ";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a[i] = 1 + rand() % 10;
    cout << a[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
minmax(a, n);
bubble(a, n);
}

void minmax(int arrays[], int l) {
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    int min = arrays[i], imin = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < l; j++) {
        if (arrays[j] < min) {
            min = arrays[j];
            imin = j;
            k++;
        }
    }
    if (imin != i) {
        int t = arrays[i];
        arrays[i] = arrays[imin];
        arrays[imin] = t;
    }
}
cout << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    cout << arrays[i] <<

        " ";
}
cout << endl <<

    "Количество шагов в методе min max = " << k << endl << endl;
}

void bubble(int arr[], int n)
{
int check = 0, i = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
{
    if (arr[k] >= arr[k + 1])
    {
        int m = arr[k];
        arr[k + 1] = m;
    }
    i++;
}
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
{
    cout << arr[k] << " ";
}
cout << endl << "Количество шагов в методе пузырька = " << i << endl << endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    if (arr[k] >= arr[k + 1]) { /* <<< */
        int m = arr[k];
        arr[k + 1] = m;         /* <<< */
    }
    i++;
}
```

В помеченных строках вы вылезаете за границы массива.

P.S. И в очередной раз: valgrind, valgrind и если ещё не - valgrind!